# German equivalent of “to twitter” or “to tweet”

Tags: translation, anglicism

I know that German borrows a lot of words from English, but German equivalents are often used, too. Example of such pair of words is *downloaden* and *herunterladen*.

I wanted to ask whether there is a German word for *to twitter/to tweet* (in the sense of *posting on Twitter*).

I known that the word [twittern](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/twittern) is used. But I believe I have heard the word *zwitschern* on TV. I have also searched internet for occasions where this word was used. It seemed to me, it was used in this meaning. (Although, as I was told [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21935180#21935180), some of my finds used zwitschern in completely different meaning. And probably sometimes this word can be used as some kind of wordplay, which a non-native speaker can easily miss.) I will list below some examples I was able to find.

So my question is:

> Which words (apart from *twittern*) are used as a verb describing posting on twitter?

Some examples with the word zwitschern that I was able to find:

> - [Obama bei Twitter: 1 Million Follower in fünf Stunden](https://www.turn-on.de/news/obama-bei-twitter-1-million-follower-in-fuenf-stunden-27687) – Obwohl der Demokrat erst drei Tweets gezwitschert hat, folgen dem mächtigsten Mann der Welt schon jetzt 2,16 Millionen Fans im sozialen Netzwerk.
> - [Und sie zwitschern doch – Türkei blockiert Twitter](http://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/twitter-tuerkei104.html).
> - [US-Präsident darf jetzt offiziell twittern](http://www.bild.de/politik/ausland/usa-praesident/jetzt-offiziell-bei-twitter-41006400.bild.html) – Jetzt darf der US-Präsident ganz offiziell zwitschern.
> - [J.K. Rowling wehrt sich gegen Westboro Baptist Church](http://www.promicabana.de/j-k-rowling-wehrt-sich-gegen-westboro-baptist-church/) – „Ich sitze hier und schaue dabei zu, wie die Iren Geschichte schreiben. Außergewöhnlich und wunderbar“, zwitscherte sie auf Twitter.

Comment: In case you're unaware, _zwitschern_ is just the literal translation of _to tweet_ -- ie birds' chirps. (_twitter_ in this context is _Gezwitscher_) I'd agree with previous answers that in the context of the messaging service as in the examples you quoted, _zwitschern_ and _Gezwitscher_ are almost exclusively used playfully if not ironically. As for other meanings, in many German dialects, _zwitschern_ can also mean _consuming an alcoholic beverage_. German Wiktionary has some more information: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zwitschern

Comment: @BernhardReiter: I didn't know the alcoholic meaning, but there isyet another one: In the language ofcomic book/movie gangsters, "zwitschern" refers to releasing confidential information, e.g. under torture.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are in principle two words that you can use without any hidden irony (that *zwitschern* would include for free) namely:

> twittern
>
> tweeten

The first one would be the more commonly used one, whose meaning is not restricted to *writing a post on Twitter* but also generally includes *being active on twitter*.

The second is rather close to *actually posting a tweet*. And note that it is only *retweeten*, never *retwittern*, if you choose to repost what another Twitter user has posted.

Answer (score 8):

Unsurprisingly enough, the word is really the same, with an additional -n to show it's a proper German verb:

> twittern

Even if you already knew as much, there's really no alternative. *Zwitschern* (lit. to tweet, the way birds do) is rarely used, and never unironically.

Comment: "einen zwitschern" is already occupied for "having a shot (drink)". Better not used.